# Table of contents for specific subsection (subsections) only

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

In my `beamer` presentation I want to create a slide, where one can quickly jump to interesting topic, so I used table of content in the following way:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \tableofcontents[sections={5},sectionstyle=hide]
\end{multicols}
```

And this worked great, but now I have too many subsubsections in subsections and now it doesn't fit on one slide.

I tried the following:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Partial table of contents}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \tableofcontents[sections={5},sectionstyle=hide]
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to have `\tableofcontents` only for specific subsections?

Comment: Could you include something that is compilable, please? :-)

Comment: How much work are you willing to do?  Unless a package already exists (never looked myself) a totally automated command like \tableofcontents will be quite complicated.  Just look at the current source code and throw in a few tests for the current section and subsection.

Comment: Well, I do not have much time to spare on this, so I'd like to use some existing solution. Maybe I'll just print subsections there, and print subsubsections for specific subsection at the begining of such...

Comment: What I meant is that you could always just create a fake table of contents using \hyperlink and \hypertarget.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201314/how-to-make-a-meta-table-of-contents-for-a-table-of-contents/201341#201341 for an example.